# informatica powercenter express pass variable to multiple mappings

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Background: I am new to Informatica. Informatica powercenter express Version: 9.6.1 HotFix 2

In my etl project I have several mappings to load different dimension and fact tables in a data mart. The ETL will run daily, one requirement is to add a audit key as a column to each of these tables. The audit key is an integer and is generated from a audit table (next value from the audit key column (primary key)). So everyday the audit key is increased by 1 etc. So after each etl load, all the new or updated rows in all tables (dimension/fact) will have this audit key in a column. The purpose is the ability to trace when or how each row is inserted/updated etc.

Now the question is how to generate such key and pass on to all the mappings? The key should be from the next value from auditkey column of audit table.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a mapplet that generates/maintains the key you want and use it in all your workflows

Answer (score 0):

If you have a RDBMS source, I would suggest creating a oracle sequencer in the DB and create oracle function to get the next value...

Call the the newly created oracle function in SQL Override and use the next value sequence number in all the mapping